# Drupal 7.12 : views filters

Tags: views

i have a mark as checkbox field with two options - published and unpublished.
i want articles marked as 'published' to appear on a view page and those marked as 'unpublished' to appear after the published items as an attachment to the view. the unpublished articles will only be visible to the author. How can i go about achieving this? I have tried using the filter but to no avail. i chose the field name and selected 'is one of' then selected publish, but this did not work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drupal contains a published/unpublished feature by default, which can be filtered in views using the `Content: Published` filter.

If you want to use a custom field though it should be as simple as you described. Assuming the published field is a taxonomy reference, you should be able to apply a filter to that field and select 'is one of' and the appropriate term (published). I tried this and it works.

As for the second part, you can clone the view and change the field filter to unpublished. Then add a `Content: Author` relationship and a `User: Current (Yes)` filter to filter it to content that the current user has authored (you might also want to put some access restrictions on this view). This view can then be added to the 'Footer' section of the first view.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I used cck field. I will try taxonomy reference and see how it goes. thanks again

Comment: It worked, thanks. I used an attachment to display the unpublished articles. However, the title of the attachment is not appearing. I override the title in the contextual filter. the title is showing in the view preview but not on the actual page. Is there anything am missing?